# Build Visual Studio package (template) structure manually

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to create an application for File management system.

This is how project structure should look like:

[image]

I have managed to download needed files from GitHub:

[image]

Is there any guide how to add them all to Visual Studio Project to get it working?

There is VaultApplication.cs in src folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the files to your project's folder, then, right-click on the project node (`MyCompany.MyProduct.MyVaultApplication1`). Select Add>Existing Items. And then add the files and folders you just moved.

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, moving the files to your project's folder isn't 100% necessary, but I think it makes things easier to manage.

[image]

Comment: You don't even need to move them (IIRC). If you just go through the normal add process it'll copy them to the directory if they don't exist. If you didn't want to move them you'd click the little dropdown arrow on the Add button and do "Add as link"

Comment: I'm not so sure. I just tried adding a file to one of the solutions I work with and it didn't seem to copy over to the project's folder. Though that does raise a good point. You don't have to move them if you don't want to, but it seems like it'd be easier to manage with moving them.